# Como verificar se um ID possui informações diferentes em um período de tempo?

Tags: r, group-by, filter

Tenho a seguinte base de dados: cnpj_raiz, identificador_matriz_filial (1 = matriz, 2 = filial), uf, ativa_em_2017, ativa_em_2018, ativa_em_2019, ativa_em_2020 (NA= inativa, 1 = ativa).

O que eu preciso: identificar, por uf e ano, a quantidade em empresas cuja matriz fica em outro estado.

Ex simples:

```
cnpj | Matriz_filial | Uf | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020
123       1            SP    1       1     1       1
123       2            BA    0       0     1       1 
123       2            BA    0       0     1       1 
123       2            SP    1       1     0       0 
456       1            SP    0       1     1       1
456       2            BA    0       0     1       0
```

> BA = 2 em 2019 e 1 em 2020 (a matriz fica em SP)
> SP = 0 (matriz e filial no mesmo estado)

Resultado esperado de acordo com a base exemplo:

> BA = 1 em 2017, 1 em 2018, 1 em 2019, 0 em 2020 (tem apenas filiais
> nesse estado, a matriz está em outro)
>
> SP = 1 em todos os anos (tem apenas filiais nesse estado, a matriz
> está em outro)
>
> GO = 1 em todos os anos (tem apenas filiais nesse estado, a matriz
> está em outro)
>
> Todos os demais = 0 em todos os anos (matrizes e filiais no mesmo
> estado)

Depois eu preciso plotar um gráfico: y = Quantidade, x = Ano, group = uf.

Tentei criar uma coluna flag para identificar, mas não está dando certo.

```
empresa %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(cnpj_raiz, identificador_matriz_filial, uf),
    names_to = 'Ano'
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(cnpj_raiz, identificador_matriz_filial, uf, everything()) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(cnpj_raiz, identificador_matriz_filial, uf) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    inclui_matriz_na_uf = all(1:2 %in% c(identificador_matriz_filial)),
    inclui_matriz_na_uf = ifelse(inclui_matriz_na_uf == T, 'Sim', 'Não')
    ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Ano = stringr::str_extract(Ano, "[0-9].*")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(inclui_matriz_na_uf == 'Não')
```

Exemplo da base:

```
structure(list(cnpj_raiz = c("6565656", "6565656", "77777","63547", "63547", "63547", "63547", "63547", "63547", "202102", "789654", "632145", "96896", "5555469", "5555469", 
"5555469", "6665554", "123321", "2703001", "270307171", "2220258", "878787", "878787", "234209", "717400", "737410", "98598","99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", 
"99992225", "99992225", "2252221", "96665123", "917800", "8920071", "9461800", "100553", "5571114", "7038010", "494001"), identificador_matriz_filial = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), uf = c("PB", "PB", "RS", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "SE", "BA", "AL", "BA", "PR", "PR", "PR", "RJ", "SP", "CE", "RJ",   "SP", "BA", "SP","SP", "SP", "MT", "PE", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO",  "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "MA",  "GO", "PE", "PE", "MG", "SP", "PI", "SP", 
"RJ"), ativa_em_2017 = c(1L,  1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA,  NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA,  1L), ativa_em_2018 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA,  NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), ativa_em_2019 = c(1L, 1L, NA,
1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L,  NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), ativa_em_2020 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei com 2 agregações. A primeira com o cnpj e o uf para criar a coluna flag para os pares sem filial. E na segunda fiz a soma dos valores das flags por uf e ano, que são as informações que você quer plotar.

```r
empresa <- structure(list(cnpj_raiz = c("6565656", "6565656", "77777","63547", "63547", "63547", "63547", "63547", "63547", "202102", "789654", "632145", "96896", "5555469", "5555469", 
                                      "5555469", "6665554", "123321", "2703001", "270307171", "2220258", "878787", "878787", "234209", "717400", "737410", "98598","99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", "99992225", 
                                      "99992225", "99992225", "2252221", "96665123", "917800", "8920071", "9461800", "100553", "5571114", "7038010", "494001"), identificador_matriz_filial = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), uf = c("PB", "PB", "RS", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "SE", "BA", "AL", "BA", "PR", "PR", "PR", "RJ", "SP", "CE", "RJ",   "SP", "BA", "SP","SP", "SP", "MT", "PE", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO",  "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "MA",  "GO", "PE", "PE", "MG", "SP", "PI", "SP", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "RJ"), ativa_em_2017 = c(1L,  1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA,  NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA,  1L), ativa_em_2018 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA,  NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), ativa_em_2019 = c(1L, 1L, NA,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L,  NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), ativa_em_2020 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
library(magrittr)
empresa %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(cnpj_raiz, identificador_matriz_filial, uf),
    names_to = 'Ano'
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na(value) %>%  #Remove os anos não ativos
  dplyr::select(cnpj_raiz, identificador_matriz_filial, uf, everything()) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(cnpj_raiz, uf) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    uf_sem_matriz = ifelse(any(identificador_matriz_filial == 1, na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0, 1)
    ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Ano, uf) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(
    qtd_filiais = sum(uf_sem_matriz, na.rm=TRUE),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Ano = stringr::str_extract(Ano, "[0-9].*")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(qtd_filiais != 0)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    Ano   uf    qtd_filiais
#>    <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 2017  BA              1
#>  2 2017  GO              7
#>  3 2017  SP              1
#>  4 2018  BA              1
#>  5 2018  GO              8
#>  6 2018  SP              1
#>  7 2019  BA              1
#>  8 2019  GO              8
#>  9 2019  SP              1
#> 10 2020  GO              8
#> 11 2020  SP              1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado! É quase isso. O problema é o seguinte: todas as filiais da mesma empresa devem contar como 1 no mesmo estado/ano. Exemplo: em GO apesar de terem 8 filiais, conta apenas como 1 empresa.

Comment: Opa, resolvi ! Adicionei um `unique()` entre o `group_by()` e o `summarize()`. Valeu!